How do I see in musical notation a rhythm I tap on the computer accurately?
I intend to do rhythmic and timing studies on songs that I plan to play. One exercise would be to mark the timing of the notes in a solo within the correct beat and meter, using, for example, the sound of a single note and its respective durations, abstracting from the complexity and technique of the music, simply training to be on time and precise with rhythm. For that, I need musical feedback. How can I see on the screen the timings on musical notation I give by tapping to match a metronome beat, and with which software can I do this with precision and sensitivity?

There may be solutions, as John's answer shows. Unfortunately, you're asking for recommendations about a possible software or feature/usage in some program, and we normally consider such questions as off topic. Note that if you already have tried to solve your issue with a program (or specific approach) you currently use, you could [edit] your question and explain us your attempts/doubts, which would make your post more specific. This may be asked on the [chat] (but you need 20 rep), so consider checking https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Somehow you want musical rhythm notation to come from this effort. But you haven't mentioned what you already know. Can you read music? Have you studied any rhythm methods?

Any DAW or digital audio workstation that also contains music notation features will be able to somewhat interpret what you play into rhythmic notation. We do not make software recommendations on this site, but there are many of these programs available, and some of them are free or very inexpensive. There are a few things to consider:
Tapping on a computer is not really a great option because of timing issues. See comments by @musicamante. The best thing to do is to input using some type of MIDI device. A keyboard or a trigger pad playing a repeated single note are the most obvious options.
You have to use the internal metronome of the program and play along to the click as precisely as possible in order for the program to interpret what you play correctly.
You have to play standard note durations and subdivisions that the computer will recognize. If you play non standard rhythms the computer will probably interpret what you do as something overly complex and almost unreadable.
The basic process is to create a track, record your rhythm to a metronome, and then generate music notation for that track. The process will be slightly different for each system and will require learning how to use your chosen program for that purpose.
One final point: you can’t assume the computer will interpret everything correctly and blindly accept what the program says, you have to be able to read and understand music notation and edit what is there if you want it to be accurate.

I'd add some related notes, as, even if they may not be strictly important to the case at hand (the OP probably is not interested in such accuracy), it's still good to be aware of them. Many programs allow input through the computer keyboard, but using it is not fully reliable for rhythmical purposes for at least 3 reasons: 1. the travel distance of a key doesn't always match the point in which the key is actually triggered with the end of its course; 2. the release point may not be at the same distance of the press one, so the duration may be inconsistent (this may also happen with standard »

» instruments, obviously); 3. depending on how keyboard input is implemented in the program, it may take too much time to map a pressed key to the actual note (or while being occupied doing something else, such as scrolling and redrawing part of the screen), causing inconsistent timings; 4. depending on the keyboard hardware, multiple key presses may cause "jamming", limiting the amount of detected pressed keys, with the result that some key presses may be missed when too many keys are already down, and unexpected key presses are then triggered when one previously pressed key is released »

» afterwards (see Key rollover). And all this obviously has to relate with the ability of the program to eventually quantize "intelligently", and how quantization is actually considered: some directly do it on input, meaning that the actual note start and end is quantized during playback (so the original timing data is fundamentally lost), others do it only when entering the possible notation view, which is normally the case for programs that provide notation as a secondary feature only. Also, few programs provide configuration for quantization.

When I first used Sibelius to turn midi into notation I was disappointed because it notated exactly what I'd played - I hadn't played a crotchet, I'd played a double-dotted quaver, and my note didn't start on the barline, it started a 32-note before.
The produced notation was full of ties and semiquaver beams - it was accurate but unusable.
Better to snap your performance to a timing grid, so that you end up with reasonable notation. You don't really want accuracy, you want legibility!
